# Does tag [nativelibrary] serve a purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags

[[nativelibrary]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativelibrary) appears to be a mildly irrelevant tag that is used approximately 160 times on SO.  It has no description other than one that I attempted to provide it recently, but even that description is just an attempt to fit a square peg in a round hole.

It is primarily used:

1. either in conjunction with [JNI] / [JNA] / [java.library.path] (all redundant with [nativelibrary], IMHO), or where any of those more relevant tags are not applied.
2. applied to a question where the tag is overshadowed by more relevant tags
3. on random questions referencing native libraries entirely unrelated to one-another such that a search against the tag does not produce results that would help someone searching the tag.

I am of the opinion that this tag should be removed from all questions qualified under items 1 and 2 above, then re-evaluated for relevance.

At worst, it should be renamed to [native-library] (added hyphen).

Comment: Good points. A native library could be something from ruby or something from java. If someone is having trouble with a native library in a specific language, it could be easier to search for using that language tag like `ruby` or `java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have a tag wiki and it's completely unclear what it's actually referring to. As mentioned in your post it has a wide range of tags associated with it, from [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) to [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop).

It is something that needs to be clear and specific, native library for what?. I'd recommend either burning the tag or creating native-library specific tags e.g. [android-native-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-native-library).

Comment: Slowly burning the tag.

Comment: Down to 50; fit them all on a single page, today.

Comment: Aaaaaaand DEAD.

Comment: @JoshDM :D good work